# Facebook FQL Query Event_member "Inviter" and "Inviter_type"

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-fql, developer-tools

In the [description of the FQL event_member page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member), it says that the column `inviter` should inform us about the ID of the user or page who invited a UID at the event, and `inviter_type` should inform us about whether the inviter was a user or a page. I have tried these functions on both public events and an event that I have created myself, but it always fails.

> "inviter": null   and  "inviter_type": ""  for every user.

Is this a bug, an old function that works no more, or a new function that does not work yet?

Comment: Understand that this function would be awesome, making it possible to view who was the most influent user or page in sending invitations to an event and possibly allow her to co-host the next Facebook event if only to make sure she spreads the invitation into her network.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that **you only** are allowed to know who invited **you** and how.

The only command that will make the `inviter` and `inviter_type` attributes useful is:

```
select eid, uid, inviter, inviter_type, rsvp_status 
from event_member where eid=EVENT_ID and uid=me()
```

In that case, you are exactly looking for the person who invited you to an event you've been invited to!

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "eid": 3811052099231, 
      "uid": 1022369839, 
      "inviter": 1406101549, 
      "inviter_type": "user", 
      "rsvp_status": "attending"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: ". But in no way you will be able to know who invited any random user. "   You can on the website itself - Hover over the little mail icon