# get inviter from fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to find out who invited each of the users from an event in facebook. I'm the admin of the event.
Is there any way to do so?

I tried using the `inviter` from `event_member`, but it returns `null` for all users, except myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook FQL Query Event\_member "Inviter" and "Inviter\_type"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675640/facebook-fql-query-event-member-inviter-and-inviter-type)